# Multiple slideshows on one page error with jQuery - Some pictures are excluded

Tags: jquery, html, slideshow

I have created a slideshow using jQuery, however for some reason some of the pictures in the slideshow are not sliding as they should. For example: If slideshow 1 has 5 pictures it will only show the first two pictures and cycle through them.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="this_page">
        <div class="container band_1">
            <div class="sub_container">
                <img class="mySlides1" src="../art/photo-12.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides1" src="../art/photo-13.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides1" src="../art/photo-10.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides1" src="../art/photo-14.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides1" src="../art/photo-11.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides1" src="../art/photo-15.jpg">
                <button class="button left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 0)">&#10094;</button>
                <button class="button right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 0)">&#10095;</button>         
            </div>
            <div class="sub_container">
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container band_2">
            <div class="sub_container">
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sub_container">
                <img class="mySlides2" src="../art/photo-21.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides2" src="../art/photo-22.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides2" src="../art/photo-20.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides2" src="../art/photo-23.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides2" src="../art/photo-24.jpg">
                <button class="button left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 1)">&#10094;</button>
                <button class="button right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 1)">&#10095;</button>         
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container band_1">
            <div class="sub_container">
                <img class="mySlides3" src="../art/photo-16.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides3" src="../art/photo-17.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides3" src="../art/photo-18.jpg">
                <button class="button left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 2)">&#10094;</button>
                <button class="button right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 2)">&#10095;</button>         
            </div>
            <div class="sub_container">
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container band_2">
            <div class="sub_container">
                <h1>Hello</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sub_container">
                <img class="mySlides4" src="../art/photo-25.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides4" src="../art/photo-26.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides4" src="../art/photo-27.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides4" src="../art/photo-28.jpg">
                <img class="mySlides4" src="../art/photo-29.jpg">
                <button class="button left" onclick="plusDivs(-1, 3)">&#10094;</button>
                <button class="button right" onclick="plusDivs(1, 3)">&#10095;</button>         
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
var slideIndex = [1,3];
var slideId = ["mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3", "mySlides4"]
showDivs(1, 0);
showDivs(1, 1);
showDivs(1, 2);
showDivs(1, 3);

function plusDivs(n, no) {
    showDivs(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
}

function showDivs(n, no) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex[no] = 1}
        if (n < 3) {slideIndex[no] = x.length}
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";  
            }
            x[slideIndex[no]-1].style.display = "block";  
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

P.s. Just a side note question, what size file of jpegs would be best for websites?

Comment: can you post your code online to view what is the problem? 

for your side question it is good to check your website on GTMetrics and it will returns to you optimized images

Answer (score 0):

Try changing var index into:

```
var slideIndex = [1,1,1,1];
```